# “Failed to configure php55-mysql” with MacPorts and Percona 5.5

Tags: macports

I'm getting this error trying to install or update Percona using MacPorts on Max OS X (Mavericks 10.9 in my case)

```
--->  Configuring php55-mysql
Error: Failed to configure php55-mysql, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php55-mysql/work/php-5.5.15/ext/mysql/config.log
Error: org.macports.configure for port php55-mysql returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port php55-mysql for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php55-mysql/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

**UPDATE (2014-11-11):** @Mark asked what was in the `main.log`. I did not save it originally but I just had the exact same problem on a different machine and here is what was in the `main.log` file:

```
[stuff above snipped]

:info:configure checking for the location of libz... /opt/local
:info:configure configure: error: Cannot find libmysqlclient under /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php54-mysql/work/percona.
:info:configure Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php54-mysql/work/php-5.4.34/ext/mysql" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-php-config=/opt/local/bin/php-config54 --with-zlib-dir=/opt/local --with-mysql=/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php54-mysql/work/percona --with-mysqli=/opt/local/lib/percona/bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql=/opt/local/lib/percona/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-sock=/opt/local/var/run/percona/mysqld.sock 
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure Failed to configure php54-mysql, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php/php54-mysql/work/php-5.4.34/ext/mysql/config.log
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port php54-mysql returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
    while executing
"proc-org.macports.configure-configure-0 org.macports.configure"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for php54-mysql: org.macports.install org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port php54-mysql for details:
```

Comment: What is in the log file so we can see the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [How to Update a Percona Installation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Update+a+Percona+Installation) gave me the clue I needed to fix the problem. I'm not going to delve into it here but the gist is that Percona had to rename `libmysqlclient` to `libperconaserverclient`. The fix in that article doesn’t apply to OS X/MacPorts but this fixed the issue.

```
cd /opt/local/lib/percona/mysql
sudo ln -s libperconaserverclient.a libmysqlclient.a
sudo ln -s libperconaserverclient.dylib libmysqlclient.dylib
```

Then complete your install/update.